# What are the three hidden sentences within the three sentences?

Tags: steganography

The following three sentences, written in bold below, each contain another sentence within, which you can discover with all the information in the that sentence itself. The same solving trick applies to all of the sentences. But the sentences don't particularly relate.

You'll know it once you see it.

> **Unless dermal standards myelate solely willingly, energy tangentially gullies into uric membranes, orbitally, eventually.**
>
> **Iodine cannisters, notwithstanding, bear twosomes live within outer units.**
>
> **Theremin arsenals reverberate sunsets to connect tin units.**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For each sentence,

> Take the first syllable of each word and read it phonetically (ignore the rest).

Specifically, each sentence can be deciphered as follows:

*Unless dermal standards myelate solely willingly, energy tangentially gullies into uric membranes, orbitally, eventually.*

> Un-der-stand my sole(soul) will en-tang-gull(entangle) in ur(your) mem-or-e(y)

*Iodine cannisters, notwithstanding, bear twosomes live within outer units.*

> I can not bear two(to) live with-out u(you).

*Theremin arsenals reverberate sunsets to connect tin units.*

> There ar(e) re-suns(reasons) to con-tin-u(e)

Answer (score 10):

I think I got the basic idea, but either I am missing something, or the  message is not quite in RP English.

It seems that you get the other sentences by

> taking the first syllable of each word as it is pronounced.

These are the results after some pretty liberal interpretations, hopefully I didn’t get too inventive:

> Understand my soul will entangle in your memory.
>  I cannot bear to live without you.
>  There are reasons to continue.