# What are the 3 sentences hidden within the 3 sentences?

Tags: word, steganography

Similar, to the [previous "3 sentences" question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68871/what-are-the-three-hidden-sentences-within-the-three-sentences) The following three sentences, written in bold below, each contain another sentence within, which you can discover with all the information in the that sentence itself. The same solving trick applies to all of the sentences. But the sentences don't particularly relate.

You'll know it once you see it.

> **Kathmandu venue cannot forget to Piano Stimy.**
>
> **Banshee verses, chichi story, egrets exit.**
>
> **Outtake into Sonny’s Rabbit Chorus: Vilify Vinyl.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to:

> take the final syllables of each word, which gives:

*Kathmandu venue cannot forget to Piano Stimy.*

> Do you not get to know me?

*Banshee verses, chichi story, egrets exit.*

> She says she re-grets it.

*Outtake into Sonny’s Rabbit Chorus: Vilify Vinyl.*

> Take two knees, it is fi-nal. (or *toonies* for the Canadian?)